# Combinatorics prove $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Use combinatorics consideration to prove that $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}}$ is an integer number

I have no idea what the question wants?
Does it want to prove it combinatoricaly or with binomial thoerm?

Comment: Prove it combinatorially.

Comment: @player3236 its like asking to do P(2n,2n)/${2^{n}}$?

Comment: By the definition of $2n!$, it would have $n$ multiples of $2$ within it...

Comment: __Hint:__ In a competition of $2n$ people, how many ways can we achieve a 2-way tie for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... $n$th positions?

Comment: **Hint:** How many ways are there to arrange $n$ pairs of items, where the items within a pair is indistinguishable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should convert it into a word problem. (Number of ways of arranging / permuting $2n$ objects). I believe you can figure that out. I will give an example below.

*The above number $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$ is the number of distinct permutations of two copies of $n$ objects. Thus, it is an integer.*

Comment: Like say $\{x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2,....,x_n,x_n\}$? There are $(2n)!$ arrangements and every arrangement can be written $2^n$ 'different' ways? I'm just curious for myself

Comment: @nolemonnomelon  Yes. It takes the form $\frac{(2n)!}{2!^n}$. Switching $x_i$ with its copy leaves the permutation unchanged. So you factor out a $2$ for each copy (which is hence done $n$ times).

Comment: Thanks, so effectively when we first wrote them all out we didn't take order of the elements into consideration, but then we note that switching $x_i$ with its copy leaves the permutation unchanged, so we need to group together all the elements that are alike? There are $2^n$ elements grouped together, thus the number groupings is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon I believe we mean the same. If your set is $\{x_1,x_2,x_2,x_2,x_3\}$ without considering equality of elements, we can permute this in $5!$ ways. Now the $x_2$s can be permuted among itself in $3!$ ways leaving the set of permutations unchanged. Thus, the number of permutations will be $5! / 3!$.

Comment: Thank you! Welcome to MSE :)

Comment: No problem. Love it here.